# Affected Rows not working - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have this delete function in my model. When you press the delete button, it will subtract the number of total notes from the total notes column in my database.  For eg. if you had 200 notes, and you deleted one of them, it will be 199 notes AND the note will be deleted from the database.

My code:

```
public function entry_delete($pid) {

        $uid=$this->session->userdata('uid');

        $whereConditions = array('pid' => $pid, 'uid' => $uid);
        $this->db->where($whereConditions);
        $this->db->delete('dayone_entries');

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 0) {
            $sql_entry = "UPDATE users set total_entry = total_entry - 1 WHERE uid = $uid";
            $this->db->query($sql_entry);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
}
 }
```

But this doesn't work. I don't know why but when I press  the delete button from my view, it will delete it from the database AND subtract -1 from my total_entry table. However, if I comment out the

```
$this->db->delete('dayone_entries');
```

It will still subtract 1 from the total_entry.

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't be `affected rows > 0`, after the deletion was made, then make the subtraction on the other table. your if condition is inverted, if `affected rows == 0` (no affected rows), then make subtraction, that doesn't make sense

Comment: @Ghost so how exactly can I fix it?

Comment: the answer is already above, change the if condition

Comment: @Ghost The first two words: "shouldn't be". Do you mean "It shouldn't be" or "Shouldn't it be"?

Comment: I would really aprrecate it if you rephrased it. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for my english, i'm not a native speaker, anyway, shouldn't it be `affected rows > 0` if you want to make the subtraction after the deletion was made

Comment: no need to :) actually you can answer your own question, its valid here on SO, im just glad that helped

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have fixed this yet, but I think what Ghost was saying is your

```
if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 0) {}
```

is doing the wrong check. If you only want it to trigger if the rows where successfully deleted you would want to check

```
if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {}
```

This is saying if the affected rows is more than 0 then do this. In CodeIgniter is says that the `affected_rows()` method is for "doing 'write' type queries (insert, update, etc.)".

It then goes on to say "Note: In MySQL "DELETE FROM TABLE" returns 0 affected rows. The database class has a small hack that allows it to return the correct number of affected rows. By default this hack is enabled but it can be turned off in the database driver file." So if your `if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 0) {}` is triggering in both situations then this hack could be disabled because your asking "if the affected rows equals zero do this" and it should't trigger if your delete was successful.